# Trying to access hidden field in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not able to access a hidden field in my view from an action in my controller. Here is the code...

routes.rb

```
  match 'csv' => 'registrations#export_csv', :as => :csv
```

controller

```
  def export_csv
    @registration_date = params[:registration_date]
    @registrations = Registration.where("DATE(created_at) = ? ", @registration_date)
    csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["Name", "ID"]
       @registrations.each do |r|
         csv << [r.name, r.student_id]
       end
     end
     send_data(csv, :type => 'test/csv', :filename => 'add_hoc.csv')
  end
```

view

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'registration_date', @registration_date %>
<%= link_to 'Export CSV', csv_path, :registration_date => @registration_date %>
```

In my controller @registration_date is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You **don't need a hidden field if you want to send your registeration date in link_to** so remove that and Try*:

```
<%= link_to 'Export CSV', csv_path(registration_date: @registration_date) %>
```

Comment: Boom! You nailed it. Thanks!